# React/Django Application working on local but not on production

Tags: django, reactjs

I'm developing an application in Django and React. When I locally host the server and frontend, the application works fine and cookies get sent on requests that they need to be sent on since I set the axios defaults for withCredentials to true. However, when I deploy my frontend to production and try to access views with login required on my server, I continuously get 404 errors meaning the authentication is failing. I have tried a bunch of different solutions but seem to be really stuck on what this issue may be.

Comment: On the frontend, log error to the console or get the error from the network tab in developer tools and add it in your question. The issue you are facing is probably CORS related but I can only be sure once I see the error. Questions with code and error details are easier to answer correctly

Comment: I actually was able to fix it with this:
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None